# Java CLI arguments syntax for object initialization

Tags: java, parsing, properties, posix, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for a tool which will allow me use command-line-style (preferably POSIX) strings to initialize an object' properties and attributes.

For example, you'd provide it with `String` input formatted like so:

```
String input = "--firstName=John --MiddleName=\"Louis Victor\" --lastName=Smith";
```

... and it would `setFirstName("John")`, `setMiddleName("Louis Victor")` and `setLastName("Smith")` on a given object. (which could be a JavaBean)

Please note that the input is a single `String`, not an array `String[]` as is the case with many popular CLI argument "parsers".

This is all similar to [args4j](https://args4j.dev.java.net/) but I couldn't get that to work... and I'm hoping to avoid using `@annotations`.

Does anyone have code/libraries/tools which could accomplish this?

Comment: pendant mode on: `-firstName John` is not posix-style. `--first-name John` is posix-style. You are using some (the same?) odd windows/nix mix that java.exe using (`-version`? seriously?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a Java library to parse POSIX-style command line parameters. I used [JSAP](http://martiansoftware.com/jsap) some time ago and it was really cool (it was using XML configuration back then).

Comment: It's looking like JSAP in combination with [Apache Commons' BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) is going to be my ticket.

Answer (score 4):

For your use case, forget regular CLI parsers, you need a custom-tailored solution. If you really have such a simple argument syntax (parameters always begin with `--`, no occurrences of `--` in the parameter values), you can use a simple [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)-based solution like this class:

### Parse the String Arguments

```
public class ArgParser{

    // split on (optional whitespace) + "--"
    private final Splitter paramSplitter = Splitter.on(
        Pattern.compile("\\s*\\-{2}")).omitEmptyStrings();

    // find key=value (with optional double quotes around value)
    private final Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern
        .compile("(.+?)=\"?(.*?)\"?$");

    public Map<String, String> getParamValues(final String posixString){
        final Map<String, String> paramValues = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        Matcher matcher;
        for(final String param : paramSplitter.split(posixString)){
            matcher = keyValuePattern.matcher(param);
            if(!matcher.find()){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad parameter: " + param);
            }
            paramValues.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
        return paramValues;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
final String input =
    "--firstName=John --middleName=\"Louis Victor\" --lastName=Smith";
System.out.println(new ArgParser().getParamValues(input));
```

**Output**

> {firstName=John, middleName=Louis Victor, lastName=Smith}

Now you can take the map and use it with a Bean library like commons-beanutils (I prefer the Spring BeanWrapper personally, but that only makes sense if you use Spring anyway)

### Define the Bean Class

Any way, I'll use this value holder class:

```
public class Name{

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Objects
            .toStringHelper(this)
            .add("first name", firstName)
            .add("middle name", middleName)
            .add("last name", lastName)
            .toString();
    }

    // + getters & setters

}
```

### Set the Bean Properties

Now we'll use [`BeanUtils.populate(Object, Map)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object%2C%20java.util.Map%29) to apply the parameter values, like this:

```
final String input =
    "--firstName=John --middleName=\"Louis Victor\" --lastName=Smith";
final Map<String, String> paramValues =
    new ArgParser().getParamValues(input);
final Name name = new Name();
BeanUtils.populate(name, paramValues);
System.out.println(name);
```

**Output:**

> Name{first name=John, middle name=Louis Victor, last name=Smith}

### Caveat: Supported Property Types

[`BeanUtils.populate()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object%2C%20java.util.Map%29) supports setting the following property types:

> ... String, boolean, int, long, float, and double.
>   In addition, array setters for these
>   types (or the corresponding primitive
>   types) can also be identified.

**Source:** [`BeanUtilsBean.populate(Object, Map)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#populate%28java.lang.Object%2C%20java.util.Map%29)

If you need parameter conversion beyond that, you should probably look into using the [Spring BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans) after all, it's extremely powerful, has many [built-in property editors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion) and you can add [custom property editors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration). Just change the code like this:

```
final Name name = new Name();
final BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(name);
wrapper.setPropertyValues(paramValues);
```

**Reference:**

- [`BeanWrapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html)
- [`PropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(Map)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessor.html#setPropertyValues%28java.util.Map%29)

Comment: I'm trying that, but as I understand it, I'd need to `addOption(...)` for every property of every object, or I'll get a `UnrecognizedOptionException` thrown. I need it to be more generalized than that.

Comment: You might use reflection to query classes and the populate the Option object.

Comment: @LeguRi added a different implementation now

Comment: Awesome! In the end, I used JSAP with BeanUtils, so I will accept @Tomasz Nerkiewicz's answr, but the bounty is yours!

Answer (score -1):

This

```
-firstName John -lastName Smith
```

is no POSIX, you mean

```
--firstName John --lastName Smith
```

This may be the reason, why you can't get it working.

#### Update:

As I look at the example, it doesn't look like it could be the reason.

Comment: You had me really excited for a second there :(